# Need to Create Form that saves data to DB and PDF to a directory

Tags: database, forms, pdf

The title says it all. I need to create a form that the user fills in and on submit, I want the data to go to a database and a PDF to a directory on the server.

I don't think AngularJS can do all of these things, can it? I'm very new to programming -- trying to crossover from HTML/CSS/JS to more in-depth projects.

Can anyone please suggest the best course for this? What language for the form, writing to the DB and generating a PDF? I can do the rest of the research and build it out once I have some direction.

How would you go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Ugh. I forgot to mention that PHP is not an option. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to apply the paradigm Client / Server. 
With angular.js you can build the client software for handling the form but this is not necessary... 
With a single script php you can generate the page with the form and handling the incoming data. 
You can use a standard relational database like mysql for storing it and, about the pdf, take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. I'm going to take a look at this for future use. My apologies, but I forgot to mention that PHP is not an option here. Anyway, I do appreciate your assistance. Thanks!

Comment: @user3472810 ok but you can't post a question like this without specifying the context in which you're working, the technologies and the constraints.

Comment: I know. Sorry everybody.